# Browser support

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I need to make this function **work everywhere, except IE6-7**

```
$(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,300);
})
```

Please help.

Comment: Everywhere or Everywhere with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could link in [broswer detect](http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-browserdetect/) and then do something like:

```
$(function() {
   if (!($.browser.msie() && $.browser.version.number() < 8)) {
      window.scrollTo(0,300);
   }
}
```

I suppose the better question is why do you need this?  Read more about [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is the construct that you're after I think:

if (!(jQuery.browser.msie)) { 
        window.scrollTo(0,300);
    }